# GettIng 403 Forbidden in Spring Application after migration to Spring Security 6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

We are migrating from springboot 2.5 to 3.1 and are getting issues with our security config. When we made changes to our code we ended up with authorization not being added into our headers.

```java
package com.xxx.xx.security.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoders;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtValidators;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationConverter;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;

/**
 * The Class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableCaching
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ActuatorWebSecurityConfig {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChainBasic(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                    auth.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("info", "health")).permitAll() // To bypass security for this Endpoint's
                            .anyRequest().hasRole("ACTUATOR")
            ).build();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableMethodSecurity
    @Order(2)
    public static class WebSecurityConfiguration {


        @Value("${auth0.audience}") private String audience;


        @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}") private String issuer;


        /** The AccessDeniedHandler handles all request that are denied. */
        @Autowired
        private OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oAuth2AccessDeniedHandler;

        /** The OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint handles all request that are authenticated via OAuth2. */
        @Autowired
        private OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint oAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint;



        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         *
         * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration. WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config. annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity)
         */

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChainOAuth2(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "XXX.XXX.XXX.com");
            System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "XXXX");
            System.setProperty("https.proxySet","true");
            return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                            auth.anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2ResourceServer) ->
                            oauth2ResourceServer.authenticationEntryPoint(oAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint)
                                    .accessDeniedHandler(oAuth2AccessDeniedHandler)
                                    .jwt((jwt) ->
                                            jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder()).jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())
                                    )
                    ).sessionManagement((sessionManagement) ->
                            sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    )
                    .build();
        }

        protected JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
            MyJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new MyJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
            JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
            jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
            return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
        }

        @Bean
        protected JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
            NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder)
                    JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);

            OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
            OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
            OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

            jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

            return jwtDecoder;
        }



        @Bean
        public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
            // @formatter:off
            // security will not apply to these end points, they will be totally open
            return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(
                    "/configuration/ui",
                    "/swagger-resources/**",
                    "/configuration/**",
                    "/swagger-ui/**",
                    "/v3/api-docs/**",
                    "/v3/api-docs/",
                    "/swagger-ui.html",
                    "/swagger.json",
                    "/webjars/**",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/api/swagger-ui/**");
            // @formatter:on

        }

    }
}
```

Made changes as suggested but we are getting this error now

```
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.421Z] [TRACE] Invoking BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter (7/13)
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.421Z] [TRACE] Did not process request since did not find bearer token
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.421Z] [TRACE] Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/13)
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.421Z] [TRACE] Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/13)
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.421Z] [TRACE] Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/13)
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.421Z] [TRACE] Invoking SessionManagementFilter (11/13)
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.421Z] [TRACE] Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.421Z] [TRACE] Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.421Z] [TRACE] Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (12/13)
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.421Z] [TRACE] Invoking AuthorizationFilter (13/13)
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.422Z] [TRACE] Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@711e5ae6]
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.422Z] [TRACE] Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@711e5ae6] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$1635/0x000000080178d548@4ab5ceba
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.422Z] [DEBUG] Secured POST /api/v1/manage-op-profiles/associations/?access_token=<OAUTH2_ACCESS_GENERATED_TOKEN>
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.423Z] [TRACE] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
[2023-07-20T14:40:52.423Z] [WARN ] Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Required request header 'Authorization' for method parameter type String is not present
```

Comment: Add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your `application.properties` to find where the 403 is coming from

Comment: https://pastebin.com/77wx0HKf added the logging. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have two filter chains defined without `http.securityMatcher(...)`, which means both would handle all requests. Additionally, your `@Order` annotation is on the `@Configuration` instead of the `@Bean`, which would be incorrect since you want to control the order the `SecurityFilterChain` beans themselves are processed (injected into Spring Security configuration).

Besides adjusting the `@Order` annotation, you can try adding `http.securityMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())` to the first filter chain.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would like to know why I should add the security matcher to the first filter chain. Shouldnt it be for the oauth2 filter chain?

Comment: You can configure it however it makes sense for you as my suggestion is just a suggestion. I made the suggestion because your first filter chain looked to be specific to actuator endpoints, therefore it should use a specific `securityMatcher`. By omitting the `securityMatcher` you are saying "any request", so all other requests would match your resource server filter chain. You combine that with the `@Order` annotation so that the specific filter chain matches first.

Comment: Hello this really helped thanks for that. I have edited the main post to show our updated error. Your guidance was helpful and would appreciate it greatly if you could help us with why we are getting a 400 error regarding no authorization header

Comment: Sorry @RishyRane but there's no information in your question about this new error other than what you have said "missing request header 'Authorization'". Please open a new question with all relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

403 FORBIDDEN could be produced by a number of things, however one thing I've noticed from the above is based on the OAuth2 Roles and Authorities Changes.

Spring Security 6 has made changes to how OAuth2 authorities are handled. Instead of using `.hasRole("ACTUATOR")`, can you try using `.hasAuthority("ROLE_ACTUATOR")` to check for the role. This change is consistent with the OAuth2 standard, where roles are considered authorities with the `ROLE_` prefix.

Edit - after some more reading - you only need to do this if using the `GrantedAuthorityDefaults`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#replace-hasrole-hasauthority

Comment: I added logging and got the following error while executing:

https://pastebin.com/77wx0HKf any suggestions?